# Phonegap iPhone app notification when near a location

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am creating an app for the iPhone using Cordova.
I am not very good with objective-c, but have written some plugins before, so I can if needed.

I have a list of locations (gps cords) for a chain of stores. I want to popup a notification whenever a user of the app is near one of the locations.

Does phonegap support this? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction about implementing this in objective-c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does! 
First you should have a watchPosition for getting the new position of the user if it moves.

For more information of watchPosition look here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition

Then, depending of the radius of nearness of the user to the point of interest you should notificate with the popup.

**EDIT**

If you're using google maps first you should initialize the map and call the function geolocalization, then with the function calculateNearLocation looks in the array of POIs if the distance is less than 1Km, for example. If it does, it alerts with vibration.

The code would be something as this using google maps:

```
  var watchID = null;
  function geolocalization()
  {
      //Each 3 seconds looks new position
  var options = { frequency: 3000 };
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessG, onErrorG, options);
   }
```

On success of the geolocalization:

```
  function onSuccessG(position) {
   var mipos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); 
calculateNearLocation(mipos);
 }
```

For calculating if the user's location is near a POI:

```
  function calculateNearLocation(mipos) {
   var indice = 0;
   $.each(listPOI, function() {

    var distanceBetween = Math.ceil(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(listPOI[indice].latitudes, listPOI[indice].longitudes), mipos));

    if(distanceBetween < 10000) {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);

    }
    indice++;
});
  }
```

Comment: Looks good. Thank you. But I'm still missing something... Do I keep all the coords of my point-of-interest in a plist and loop through them each time the event pops up? Or is there a more structured way of doing this?